# How to add coverflow style effect in React where the elements are rendered differently based on position

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am making a story style view for landscape screens. I have set the layout as a `grid` with 5 elements.

- 2 Previews for the previous stories
- 1 Story View with lots of controls and features
- 2 Previews for next stories

The `Preview`s are my custom components. The `View` is from a 3rd party library.

Currently, when I switch between stories, it just snaps to the new content. I want to add a coverflow style effect so that it is actually clear that something changed.

I would like to be able to do this with vanilla js / css as the bundle size is already quite big, though a library is also fine.

I tried adding css animations / transitions but when a story changes to the next one:

1. The first preview is removed from dom.
2. The second preview takes the first place.
3. The content of the previous current story is used to create a whole new Preview component.
4. The view component is replaced with one for the current current story.
5. The third preview is removed as it is now the main story.
6. The fourth preview takes place of the third.
7. A whole new Preview is created with the content of the story that just entered view.

Only the 2nd and 4th previews actually animated. The others got removed or added right away.